# Scheduling reports & data driven alerts in Amazon Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am exploring Amazon Quicksight as a cloud-based BI tool. We have some nice to have requirements like

1. Schedule Reports on a monthly basis on the same set of datasets. This needs to be delivered to the intended audience every month on a specific date
2. Data driven Alerts, where based on certain triggers an alert needs to be generated.
3. Dual axes bar charts for multiple measures in one chart. (Tableau has it)

I couldn't find the above three features in the documentation. I believe QuickSight is not capable of doing this at this moment. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is this something that the quicksight team has in its pipeline?

-Tatha

Answer (score 1):

QuickSight does support scheduled report delivery, but the other two options you mentioned aren't available right now. I have no insight to their roadmap. For data driven alerts, I would think you would want to use some other tool such as a scheduled Lambda, Kinesis, or CloudWatch Events.

For more on report delivery, see [Amazon QuickSight now supports Email Reports and Data Labels](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-quicksight-now-supports-email-reports-and-data-labels/).